# Using Expo's FileSystem readasStringAsync to read local .txt file

Tags: javascript, xml, react-native, expo

I am trying to use expo’s FileSystem readasStringAsync function to read a local .txt file in react native and am running into the following error,
`Location ‘file:///C:/Users/User/Documents/folder/Untitled.txt’ isn’t readable.`

That being said when I control click on the uri it opens the .txt file.
Here is the code I am using,

```
import * as FileSystem from ‘expo-file-system’;
(async () =>{
const response = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync( ‘file:///C:/Users/User/Documents/folder/Untitled.txt’ ).catch(
error =>{console.error(error)})
const quotes = response.json()
console.log(quotes)
})()
```

I was wondering if anyone could help me solve this issue or could suggest a better way to convert a local .txt file to string.
Thank you

Comment: maybe could you change it to not extension format? lets say Untitled without txt

Answer (score -8):

you can't use `await` inside an asynchronous function, use `.then` in the promise